# eclipse delete only left or right side of the cursor

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-plugin

I am looking for a plugin or existing feature that enables deletion of text on the right(this is more important) or on the left side of the cursor.

```
int x = | newAssignmentGoesHereButIWanttoChangequickly();
```

Assume that the pipe is cursor.

Comment: two stage method : Shift+right arrow then Del(Backspace)?

Comment: Shift+right arrow -> this requires many steps if there are several words. X x = DaoFactory.getXDao().getById(id);

Comment: shift-end + del seems like better option. But let's wait for a while if we can get sth like CTRL+D.

Comment: Shift+home then del - if you want to delete on the right side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some key combinations:
On Windows or Linux: 
<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.
On Mac:
<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd>

Comment: Actually guido suggested this first in the comments section. i think there will not be a better option.

Comment: @mertinan: Excuse me, my mistake. I was going to suggest shift+home. I'll edit answer.